# How to factor in breakpoints when measuring elapsed time in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

There are multiple methods for measuring time, e. g. `clock()`, `time()`, `std::chrono`, or `QueryPerformanceCounter`. But how do I factor in time spent in the debugger?

I'd like to know how much time I spend in total on waiting for certain functions. If I hit a breakpoint, it would invalidate the measurement, but how can I become aware of it? Is there any callback for `DebugBreak`/`_CrtDbgBreak`? I would be ok with just flagging the measurement as invalid so that I can ignore it.

Asking for Windows.

Edit: I'm asking this to measure productivity. Sometimes I get annoyed because debugging takes a long time. I have to wait 30 seconds here, 2 minutes there. It adds up. Some functions take a long time in debug builds. The question I'm trying to answer is: Does it matter? Should I do something about it? How long do I really wait for this, over the course of a month?

Comment: when you measure time you do a run without debugging

Comment: The debugger actually has nothing to do with your program... It just debugs the code during execution from a ***debugger***... When you actually build and package your program, there will be no breakpoints or anything of the sort... because you have already compiled the code...

Comment: It is not a sensible approach.  Only ever use the Release build without breakpoints to measure perf.  And use a profiler instead of cobbling it together by yourself.  Debug code only with small datasets so you never have to wait.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Also there is no point in timing debug code.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg The answer stands.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no reason to do so.  Code running in a debugger will be much slower and it is probably built without optimization.  You should build the code with optimization and run it without a debugger to measure speed.  Get the code working first using the debugger and then test the performance.  Testing performance and debugging are really two different steps.